# How can I maintain zero-copy in a native node module?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node-modules

I'm writing a native node module for an in-process database which features zero-copy data lookups. I'd like my module to also have this ability. In other words, when I get data from the database, I'd like to pass the data to V8 without the need to copy memory or the need to parse something.

How can I do this?

So far, all the ways I have seen involved either parsing back and forth between JSON (pretty much a waste of resources in this case) or instantiating V8 data structures and copying data into them.

*NOTE: in case you are wondering, zero-copy data lookup means (in a nutshell) that the database engine does not need to copy memory when it retrieves data.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution, although it is rather limited.

Interesting documentation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/v8/ (overview) and http://izs.me/v8-docs/main.html (API docs)

Seems that V8 has an `ExternalStringResource` class which can be used for this purpose:
http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1String_1_1ExternalStringResource.html

Node itself also has a `Buffer` class which can also be used for similar ends:
http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

By using the above two classes, it is possible to implement zero-copy in a native node module for strings and byte arrays. Unfortunately it seems that (at the time I'm writing this) it isn't possible for objects.

**EDIT**

In case you are okay with just having the zero-copy ability for the `string` or `Buffer` properties of the object (but not the whole object itself), it can easily be implemented using the interceptors or accessors in the V8 API.

Comment: Please don't use `izs` v8docs hosting, since it's a generated file from the ages. The one from `nodesource` should be better, https://v8docs.nodesource.com/.

Someone needs to ask @izs to take it down, really, since it's ranked very high in googles organic search. Apart from that: excellent question.

Comment: @eljefedelrodeodeljefe Thanks for the heads up. At the time I asked this, the docs you suggest didn't exist yet.

Comment: @Venemo this is great!  I am glad to hear this is possible.  I was quite worried when I learned I _must_ copy at all times.  It would really ruin my attempts at a zero copy tcp communication with node :)

Comment: @Venemo Do you have any examples of you actually doing this?